# input:valid not working for input email

Tags: html, css, input, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I know it seems dummy but I don't know why the `:valid` selector not working

I have this piece of code

**HTML**

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" value="j@gmail.com">
```

**CSS**

```
input:valid{
    border:1px solid green;
    background:red;
}
```

```css
input:valid {
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" value="j@gmail.com">
```

There's also a weird thing, it's working on the code snippet but not on JSFIDDLE, and how can I make if `value=""` to be invalid input?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following statement to declare email field.

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email " required>
```

Above statement will verify your email first.If verified successfully then form will be submit otherwise not.So you don't need to take extra effort for it.

Comment: well can I make it if it's valid, go green, if it's empty go red, if it's wrong go orange?
I've tried this
input:valid{
    border:1px solid green;
}
input:invalid{
    border:1px solid red;
}
input:required{
  border:1px solid lightgray;
}

Answer (score 2):

Include the `required` keyword in your `HTML input element`, if you do not include that it'll always be valid.

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" value="j@gmail.com" required>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'required' to make the null value to be invalid input.

Edited the code to include the invalid selector.

http://jsfiddle.net/x4xfr68k/

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" value="j@gmail.com" required>
```

CSS

```
input:invalid{
      border:1px solid green;
      background:red;
 }
```